# Cucumber: How to check specific text in a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am trying to use cucumber to check the content of a Ruby on Rails view in my app. The view displays information in a table. I want to be able to check the content of one column of that table only. When I use the web step definition `"I should see"`, then it checks the entire page. Is there any easy method for doing this?

For example: `column.should have_content("text")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capybara's built-in scoping may be a little easier to maintain than those xpaths

```
within "#id_for_your_tr"
  within('td', :class=> 'class_for_your_column')
    page.should have_content "foo"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using capybara + cucumber,
say your step is

```
Then I should see the following (#MYTABLE)
    |  FOO     | 94040     | "friendly"  |
    |  BAR     | 94050     | "competition"|
```

step definition

```
Then /^I should see the following games:$/ do |expected_table|
  table_results = page.find('#DOM_ID')
end
```

My complicated approac for you definition

```
When /^(.*) in the "([^\"]*)" column of the "([^\"]*)" row$/ do |
action, column_title, row_title|
  col_number = 0
  all(:xpath, "//*[(th|td)/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(),
'#{column_title}')]]/th").each do |element|
    col_number += 1
    break if element.has_content?(column_title)
  end
  within :xpath, "//*[(th|td)/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(),
'#{row_title}')]]/td[#{col_number}]" do
    When action
  end
end
```

to check the table structure is being genereated you can use
check the number of rows is X
page.should have_selector('table tr', :count => X)

Comment: -1. Cucumber has [built in methods](http://cukes.info/cucumber/api/ruby/1.1.6/Cucumber/Ast/Table.html) for accessing [data tables](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments). Don't reinvent it yourself.